# jQuery: Re-write $('foo+bar') selector to use $foo variable

Tags: jquery

Right now I'm using the jQuery selector `$('foo+bar')`.  Since I already have `$('foo')` stored in a variable `$foo`, I'd like to re-write my selector to use the `$foo` variable.  How do you do that?

I'm looking for something simple.  I'd rather burn a few CPU cycles by using code that's easy to understand rather than write something complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function:

```
$foo.next('bar')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`next`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next)

```
var $foo,
    $bar;

$foo = $('foo');
$bar = $foo.next('bar');
-or-
$bar = $('foo + bar');
```

Comment: `$foo.next()` will give you the next sibling, whether or not its a `bar`

Comment: @32bitkid, you are very right, i forgot to add the `'bar'` selector in that call. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

This specifies to search for bar within foo, is that what you want?

```
$( 'bar', foo )
```

Comment: Yes, using a context accomplishes the same thing.  But jQuery actually converts `$( 'bar', $foo )` into `$foo.next('bar')` before processing it.  See [this article](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery) on jQuery contexts.

Comment: Note: as per my example, it would be `$('bar', $foo)`.  (When storing jQuery objects as variables, programmers begin the variable with a $ sign.)